# XCode 7.2 and Unity 5.3.0f iOS build issue

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

After several attempts at downloading 5.3.1 version of Unity3D, and not being able to do it successfully, ended up downloading 5.3.0 version from the torrents link pointed to by the unity3d download page.

Now have the environment setup to 5.3.0 of Unity 3D and XCode 7.2 
Downloaded the cardboard unitypackage as specified in the link @https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/get-started-ios

When I imported the package, I got a bunch of errors but was able to fix them by moving the required files into the MonoDevelop IDE.

Now I exported this as an iOS project using build settings, it did create a folder with iOS corresponding code. However seeing the following issues, which I've been trying to fix since 3 days. Tried several alternatives like switching to different versions etc, tampering with Build Settings on XCode but no luck. Can anyone please help me?

[image]

Comment: can you share the full log of error?

Comment: Here's the entire log. http://1drv.ms/1RL4Ex0